# set default value on drop down in angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to set a default value in my dropdown, but it seems I'm not able to do so.

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <select id="interfaceType" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="interfacengmodel" #interfaceType="ngModel"
    name="interfaceType" class="form-control" required  >
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Interface Name</option>
        <option *ngFor="let interface of interfaceList" [value]="interface.interfaceName">{{interface.interfaceName}}
        </option>
     </select>
     {{interfaceLocation}}
  </div>
```

I'm new to angular.
Thanks,

Comment: Can you post your fullcode first? or create demo link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select id="interfaceType" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="interfacengmodel"
```

Just set the default value (whatever it is ) to `interfacengmodel` in your component and it will become selected

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day.

Comment: @PawanTiwari Im glad it solves the issue. Consider marking this answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: How to verify a file name format in angular. My format is like ACMTTL_01_##date##~ddMMyyyy_HHmmss##date##~

Answer (score 1):

set the `interfacengmodel` as empty string

```
public interfacengmodel: UrType = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

set the value of property interfacengmodel that you want to selected as default